# Getting the missing IDs from a table by storing the records into an array and compare the set of numbers with a for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a program that gets the missing IDs of a table and the idea that I come up with is that by storing the IDs into an array and use a for loop to check if a number exists in the array and if it's existing then it is classified as a missing ID. I also used the php function - in_array() to check if a number exists in the array.

This is the code that I came up with, but I ended up with just displaying the numbers from the for loop.

```html
<?php
 include 'dbconnect.inc'; //just to the the dbconnect for connecting into the database.

 $numbers = array(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9);
 $arrlength = count($numbers);

  $query = "SELECT id FROM existing";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $existing = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $existing[] = $row;
  }
  
  for ($i=0; $i<7358; $i++) {
   if (in_array($i, $existing)) {
    echo $i . " is a missing ID <br>";
   } elseif(!in_array($i, $existing)) {
    echo $i . " exists in the table <br>";
   }
   
  }

?>
```

I prefer this solution than using the temporary tables in an SQL because it takes more than to load the query and it would not be good for a webpage.

Hope that you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: What MySQL version? If you `SELECT id FROM existing WHERE id < 7358 ORDER BY id` you'll eliminate the while loop.  Is an output like `12 - 93 are missing ID` suitable - could be a little easier. Is there an actual question you want answered or just a better version of what you have?

Comment: I'm sorry. These lines are not included: 
 $numbers = array(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9);
 $arrlength = count($numbers);

Comment: There are 7358 records

Comment: numbers/arrlength aren't used. Edit your question. And then actually ask a question. What MySQL version?

Comment: it's version 8. The ids from the table are from id number 160886 up to 169197. There are missing/skipped id in the table and I want to get those using php codes and not just through sql.

Comment: Why do you need the missing IDs? This sounds like it could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I need those missing IDs for auditing and inspection.

Comment: This is a bit of a non-answer. If its auto_increment, gaps can occur for reasons other than the row was deleted.

Comment: I feel like this is misguided

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=71):

To get missing ranges:

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS 'Missing From', MIN(b.id)-1 AS 'Through'
FROM existing AS a
JOIN existing AS b ON a.id < b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING a.id+1 < MIN(b.id)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=912c18bb8ea26bf210821718f315da7a)

Comment: Thanks Dan for this. It's has always been the solution that I have been seeing. I already tried this out on this program(testing program) it works just right, but what if I have more than 70000 records? Do you have any other solution? It actually takes a lot of time to return the results.

Answer (score 0):

User variables are only evaluated when sent, so using a `HAVING NOT (gap_from=0 AND gap_to=0)` clause isn't possible as an optimization (see [user variables manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)). A such we use the "sending" to be sending to the temporary table to save a larger time full of data that is about to be discarded.

The temporary table uses the primary key ensure there will only be one (0,0) entry that occurs when the there is no gap. Inserting subsequent existing entries (0,0) gets ignored resulting in a minimal table of gaps.

The remainder of the table is the gaps in the sequence:

```
create table existing (id  int unsigned not null)

insert into existing values (3),(5),(6),(7),(8),(19),(20),(21),(30)

set @last=0

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE v (gap_from int unsigned, gap_to int unsigned, next int unsigned, PRIMARY KEY(gap_from, gap_to))
IGNORE SELECT IF(@last=id, 0, @last) as gap_from,
   IF(@last=id, 0, id-1) as gap_to,
   @last:=id+1 as next
FROM existing ORDER BY id

select gap_from,gap_to from v where NOT (gap_from=0 AND gap_to=0)

 gap_from | gap_to
 -------: | -----:
        0 |      2
        4 |      4
        9 |     18
       22 |     29
```

If you don't want the first gap, the one between 0 and the first entry in the table:

```
select gap_from,gap_to from v where gap_from!=0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13b19eb243993b6132301cfdbbec7cf3)*

Comment: While the reasons for wanting the gaps are a bit unclear, this is a pretty good solution right?